# Incentive Structure Biased

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-usage

Can nonhuman things have bias?

> Politicians are subject to ***an incentive structure biased toward*** the adoption of projects and programs with highly visible immediate benefits and well-hidden costs.
>   [quote source](http://books.google.com/books?id=mkAaP-3CbYwC&q=%22structure+biased+toward%22&dq=%22structure+biased+toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=upAgUZyoKsKKjAKssYCYAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwATgU)

An incentive structure is non-thinking and non-human.  So how can it be biased?

Comment: First, one of your basic premises is false: the _incentive structures_ in your sentence are all created by human beings. If you want a simple answer to your question, read just a little bit about the bias built into survey questions & verbal intelligence tests. Barrie's answer, however, should be good enough. Darwin's theory of evolution illustrates quite well the biases that exists in nature: nature isn't human or a human creation.

Comment: *Bias* may be used to mean *prejudice*, but it may be used in other senses as well.

Answer (score 1):

A bowling ball can be biased. That is, it can be deliberately weighted on one side to make the game more challenging. If a bowling ball, why not anything else?

Comment: There is a definition under "bias" concerning bowling, but none for the usage in my example.

Comment: One of the Oxford English Dictionary's definitions of the verb _bias_ is 'To give a bias or one-sided tendency or direction to; to incline to one side; to influence, affect (often unduly or unfairly).' There is no indication that it applies only to people.